# Can I use Sklearn Confusion matrix in linear regression or I should use something else to check the model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, cross-validation

I want to check what was the known value and how much difference is the model is predicting.
I tried to fit the test train split data into the confusion matrix but it is giving error [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hmE3.png)

Comment: Please add what you have done and the error trace as code snippets ;)

Comment: meti there is a screenshot of code

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing the whole trace but I am guessing that it's raising the error that your label space does not look categorical.

Short answer is no you cannot use a confusion matrix for a regression has it would be of infinite size (and useless). Confusion matrices are specific to (finite) fixed size target space.